# How to use Vite when developing a local package for Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vite

I am developing a package for Laravel locally using the link in composer.json to connect. The package contains views and I want to use the power of vite to work on them. How do I configure vite.config.json and @vite to work correctly? Is it possible to use vite globally or only locally in a package folder?

vite.config.json

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            buildDirectory: 'vendor_name/package_name',
            input: [
                'vendor_name/package_name/resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
                'vendor_name/package_name/resources/css/app.css',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

index.blade.php

```
...
{{ Vite::useBuildDirectory('vendor_name/package_name')
->withEntryPoints(['vendor_name/package_name/css/app.css']) }}
...
```

**npm run build** return error
"Could not resolve entry module "vendor_name/package_name/resources/views/**/*.blade.php".
and
"Could not resolve entry module "vendor_name/package_name/resources/css/app.css".

Vite does not see the files of my package.

**npm run build** return in html href="http://127.0.0.1:5173/vendor_name/package_name/css/app.css"

Comment: You can see some advices there : https://www.laravelpackage.com/16-assets/#vite-config-to-build-the-package-assets but for now I failed to work with...